# How to add 'Pay with stripe ' payment method on website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I have multi vendor websites and my vendors get there sale amount into their stripe account. Now i want to take fees from them for website wallet. They can recharge wallet with cc and charge them . but I NEED TO OPTION to use their stripe balance to pay. LIKE we use paytm,paypal instead CC each time. How we can provide pay with stripe option to vendors so they can pay from their stripe account balance instead CC.

We are using the word-press Doken for the multivendor website and all other functionalities are working fine. Vendor have been provided a Website wallet which they can recharge with the credit card . but we need to option to pay with stripe option. So amount will come from there stripe account to admins stripe account.

I have tried to connect with support and forums but could not find any API for this to charge their stripe account .

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right the direction to try to use `connect`. 
Basically yourself created a `Platform` Account, and connect all your vendors account as `connected` accounts [0]

Depends on your locations of your business and vendors, Stripe provide a way for you (the platform account) to `debit` from the connected account [1]

Another way is instead of let your vendor to charge the customer directly, you charge the customer and pass down the balance down to your vendor and collect your fees using `Direct Charges` [2]

Hope the above helps and point you to the right direction

- [0] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts
- [1] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits
- [2] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges

Comment: Yes for the vendors sale on website i charge the customers of which amt fees added to admin stripe ac and remaining to vendors stripe. It food order website so once they someone order i get fees to my stripe and remaining to vendors stripe. but for delivery vendor need to have balance in website wallet which they should fill from there stipe after clicking on recharge ac. With connect can i charge there stripe AC. so they will click on recharge enter amount and there stripe details and will charge there stripe ac. ?